# Calculate the MD5 hash of the string

Tags: php

```
<?php
    function renewCode( $schoolName, $certId, $barcode, $indate ){
       return strtoupper( substr( md5( $schoolName.$certId.$barcode.$indate ), 3, 8 ) );
   }
?>
```

I don't understand the function of MD5()。I mean I know the  school Name and all of data but I can not get the right return like that

For example:

the right return: `19B55890`

Md5 encryption that string "`xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.01187422.2013-03-20`"

```
   CBBDFC8D228B7FCFECCFC54FBB3C9D87
```

it's did not equal  `19B55890`

Comment: Which string you have which produces MD5 as -> 19B55890 ? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$schoolName.$certId.$barcode.$indate` does not have `.` chars in the output - that's the [concatenate operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).  That input gives a string of:

> 大连民族学院图书馆2012081507011874222013-03-20

which when hashed, gives:

> a6019b5589029bf9378cfff4c631fc7d

The substring 3,8 of which is:

> 19b55890

Also note that [MD5](http://php.net/md5) is not encryption, it's a one way hash of the input string.  It's also considered fairly insecure now; it's recommended to use SHA-256 based hashes if you're able to switch.